# How can I search for restaurants using filters with google maps android api?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to make an app that finds the users location and then searches for for example nearby restaurants. I have a method to find the users location the only thing that is left is to find the restaurants nearby the user. How can I do this? Plz Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out the [PlacePicker API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) that's native uses the [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/). For samples, Google provided it in their [googlesamples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places) github repo, you can check those out!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about any native android soultions but you can make a Get request to this Google Places API webservice

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=8.5586,76.8814&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=[Your_KEY]
```

And parse the Json to get the restaurants nearby

> location        -  Latitude,Longitude of the place
>
> radius          -  Required radius to search your request
>
> key             - Your API Key
>
> types           - Types of places to search

### Things to do to parse the results

1. Get an Api key and create a sample request in the browser, You will get a big json result something like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/3chcUFHH)
2. Goto websites like [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) which can generate POJO classes for your Json the best configuration is given below: 
   [image]
3. Download files and extract it and add them to your source code,You will get some errors at first because you may not have the annotation libraries in your `build.gradle`
4. Add these lines in your app's `build.gradle`:

   `dependencies{
              compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
              compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2-b01'
       }`
5. Sync gradle files,And In the code where you get the json String ,deserialize it with Gson like:

`YourGooglePlacesClass object=new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,YourGooglePlacesClass.class)`

Comment: Do you know how to use that way and if you do can you show me?

Comment: This will not work because I use the users position to search for restaurant within 10km. Do you know any way to do it with the users position?

Comment: *sigh* Yes,create a location listener and replace the location parameter with the lat long before making the request

Comment: C'mon bro you didn't expect us to code it completely for you right?